# Coinkite API - Method Not Allowed status: 405 using PHP cURL POST -- Why?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am getting the error:

> { "message": "Method Not Allowed", "status": 405 }

when trying to create a new receive address. According to the [API doc](https://docs.coinkite.com/api/new-update.html#new-receive) my API key has "recv" permission.

[This](https://docs.coinkite.com/api/common.html#arguments-to-endpoints) is what the API doc says about sending args to endpoints. The only required argument is the account, which I am trying to `POST` in `cURL`.

I suspect that I am not setting the `cURL` options correctly.

Here is my code:

```
$endpoint='/v1/new/receive';

$url='https://api.coinkite.com'.$endpoint;

$sign = coinkitesign($endpoint);
$API_KEY = COINKITEAPIKEY;

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("X-CK-Key: {$API_KEY}", "X-CK-Sign: {$sign[0]}", "X-CK-Timestamp: {$sign[1]}"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array('account' => '933xxxxx2A-Axxxx5','memo' => 'test1234');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a `PUT` request, not a `POST`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
```

You should always double check your accepted method in the API docs: https://docs.coinkite.com/api/new-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the solution is to use a put -- here is the code I need:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
$data = array('account' => 'xxxxxx-xxxxxx','memo' => 'test1234');
$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```